# Is it OK to indicate in job application that you work on other stuff after work?

Tags: applications

I am currently employed, and I am applying for other jobs.  When I get home, I work on other software projects, projects that I hope to launch into a startup.  Is this OK to mention in the job application?  I want them to know I am passionate about software development, but I don't want potential employers to think I would leave the company anytime.

Comment: Is the work that you are doing on your personal software project pertinent to the job you are applying for?

Comment: Maybe.  It's in web development, and the company I'm applying to does web development, although they use different languages than I'm using and are in a different domain.

Comment: The reason I thought I'd mention it is because I don't have professional experience in web development/technologies.

Comment: I may be reading this too literally but where would you actually put this on a job application? I think it can be OK to mention your personal projects (if you can leave out the startup part) but a job app wouldn't be the place to do it.

Answer (score 6):

What you do in your spare time is your own business - I wouldn't mention it to anyone.

However, you need to keep an eye out for any clauses in future contracts which stipulate that ***anything*** you work on while employed with them is ***their*** intellectual property. This is a standard clause in a lot of employment contracts.

Other such gems might include that if you quit their employ within a certain timeframe you are barred from working in your field in that city for X number of years.

Read your contract carefully before you sign it. If not provided when the job offer is extended, ask for it explicitly. And if a clause such as the above is included, ask that it be removed or modified.

Some companies will have no problem modifying or removing the clause because it's just a standard construct. Reasonable managers will also understand that you have your own priorities, and as long as you're not competing with them, or approaching their customers with your business ideas will be OK with your activities. Others, however, actively make use of this clause, and will not cooperate with you on it.

Comment: From these responses, it seems like it's not worth mentioning my personal projects in my job application.

Comment: @user2233706 - it like to point out that using multiple accounts on stack exchange is typically a no-no. You can ask a mod (they have a badge-like rhombus next to their username) to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it OK, it may be necessary.

You are going to have to make sure the company agrees the personal products are not a conflict of interest and (if you are hired) possibly get them written explicitly into the Intellectual Property Agreement part of the contract paperwork.

If the company *isn't* comfortable with this, be prepared to decide whether you want the job enough to dry aside your personal -wide hacking, or to redirect it into areas the company considers acceptable

Comment: This disclosure can help prove that the ideas and initial work predate employment and can could be very important in any later legal proceedings should it come to that.